# Visual Studio 2012 Express C# Why do I have no "Organize Using" menu option?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, editor

Using Visual Studio 2012 Express for C#, I wanted to clean up some using statements I'm not sure of, but when I go into Edit -> Intellisense -> I have no organize using option, and same thing if I right click inside the code editor of a .cs file. Does express not have this feature or something?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to right click anywhere in the class code and an organise using button should be on the context menu. That said I use Ultimate and professional so I would imagine that it is not present in express

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing happened to me.

The solution in my case was to clean and rebuild the solution, exit visual studio and reload.

Give it a try.